# Update Formik form values on checkbox change in ReactJS app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formik, yup

I am creating a form in a React app using Formik and Yup for validation. The page component has a section for shipping address and billing address. I have a checkbox in the form that will hide the billing address section if the details are identical. My problem is that if the checkbox is checked, and the user hits `submit`, the billing details are not copied over from the shipping details and thus I get an error.

My first thought was to add an `onChange` hook to the checkbox which copies the shipping details to the billing details. The 2 problems I found with this are 1) what if the user clicks the checkbox before filling out any shipping details and 2) Formik already has a default `onChange` hook. I then tried to add some code inside of the `onSubmit` hook to update the values, but this hook is not called if the billing details are invalid or empty.

How would I go about copying over all shipping details to billing details only if the checkbox is checked? I am new to Formik, React, and Yup so I suspect I will probably need to restructure the code? Below is my very simplified form component with only a name for each section and the checkbox:

```
const DetailsPage = () => {
  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        name_s: "",
        name_b: "",
        same_address_box: false,
      }}
      validationSchema={yup.object({
        name_s: yup.string().required("Required"),
        name_b: yup.string().required("Required"),
      })}
      onSubmit={(values, { setSubmitting }) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          updateOrderInfo("name_s", values.name_s); // Context hook that updates my order data once form is validated and submitted
          updateOrderInfo("name_b", values.name_b);
          setSubmitting(false);
        }, 500);
      }}
    >
      {({ values }) => (
        <Form>
          <section id="shipping-details-container"> // Shipping section
            <MyTextInput
              name="name_s"
              type="text"
              placeholder="Shipping name..."
            />
          </section>

          <section id="billing-details-container"> // Billing section
            <MyCheckbox name={"same_address_box"}>Same Address</MyCheckbox> // Checkbox
            {`${values.same_address_box}` !== "true" ? (
              <div id="hide-address-container">
                <MyTextInput
                  name="name_b"
                  type="text"
                  placeholder="Billing name..."
                />
              </div>
            ) : (
              <h1>SHOW NOTHING</h1>
            )}
          </section>

          <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
setTimeout(() => {
      updateOrderInfo("name_s", values.name_s); // Context hook that updates my order data once form is validated and submitted
      if (values.same_address_box) {
         updateOrderInfo("name_b", values.name_s);
      }
      setSubmitting(false);
    }, 500);
```

And in Yup schema make change:

```
name_b: yup.string(). when("same_address_box", {
    is: true,
    then: yup.string().required("Required")
  })
```

Comment: This does not work. I never reach `onSubmit` in the code because when I click `submit` and the `name_b` value is an empty string, yup throws an error. The `setTimeout` function is only called if all fields pass validation.

Comment: Look at update of answer

Comment: Ahh of course. Just make the validation conditional. Thanks!